# Python error message when using import

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have been having issues with importing certain packages in Python 2.7., Windows 10, 32bit. When I type:

```
import urllib2
```

I get:

```
import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
import httplib
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
import mimetools
File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
import tempfile
File "C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
import io as _io
File "io.py", line 1
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
(the arrow is pointing to 3.4.3, not to 'on')
```

Can anyone tell me why I get the Python 3.4.3 line in the end at all and is this why it is not running? I'm using Python 2.7 version. Is there a possibility that an old file from Python 3.4. that I had previously from IBM SPSS has stayed somewhere in the system files and is causing trouble? Or could it be something else? I've already checked the path variable and there are no traces of Python 3.4.3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a file named "io.py" in your current directory?

Comment: @Kevin, if you mean the Python27 directory, no, I don't.

Comment: I mean whichever directory contains the file that has `import urllib2`, or whichever directory the shell/command line was in when you opened the REPL.

Comment: The only 'io.py' that I can find is in C:\Python27\Lib

Comment: have you installed those packages?

Comment: Yes, I have, through pip install

Comment: It's curious, because "Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601)" is a version string, which you would only expect to see in the header of a REPL session, or in the output of a script that does something with `sys.version`. To just appear nakedly inside a .py file is very unusual and not something anybody would do intentionally. Makes me think that this io.py file got overwritten at some point, perhaps thanks to a shell command containing ">>" in it.

Comment: Does `C:\Python27\Lib\io.py` contain that `Python 3.4.3` string on its first line?

Comment: "if you mean the Python27 directory" - what are you doing in the Python27 directory? Are you writing your code there? Get out of that directory! There's really important stuff in there that you're likely to break by accident.

Comment: @Kevin, no, it doesn't, I checked a few times already. I have also searched the whole system through for anything that contains Python 3.4.3 and can't find anything

Comment: @user2357112 of course not, I was just asking for clarification about what was meant with current directory

Comment: `import os; print os.getcwd()` and show us what that prints.

Comment: @user2357112 good God in heaven, you're absolutely right, there is indeed   a io.py file in there and it does contain  'Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'

Would it work if i just delete this one line?

Comment: @DanaDaskalova: Unlikely. The correct course of action depends on where that file is and what else is in that file.

Comment: When I type print os.getcwd() I get
   ` >>> import os
     >>> print os.getcwd()
     C:\Users\asus `
    

which is where that io.py file is.

Comment: If `asus` is you, it should be fine to just delete that file.

Comment: @user2357112 It seems to contain some tiny programs that I've written ages ago, like the mandatory "Hello, world" thing. I'll delete it and see what happens. Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't delete the whole directory, though!

Comment: Haha, I won't. All works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
File "io.py", line 1
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
```

says that you have a file called `io.py` that doesn't contain what it should, but instead has a Python version string.

Search your system for files called `io.py` and open each one in notepad or something. One will have the version string. This is a standard library so you probably need to reinstall Python to fix it.

Comment: I did already, and none has such a thing. Do you reckon uninstalling everything would be the only way to fix it?

Comment: The error message is very explicit, and no, if you can't locate the problem then uninstalling everything is an absolute last resort. What happens if you just do `import io`?